# How to get the current user’s Delve URL via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, delve

When a user signs into my Web app via Microsoft OAuth2, I want to display her name, email address, and a link to her homepage or profile page.

I can get `displayName` and `mail` from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/`, but I haven’t found a homepage or profile URL.

The user’s Delve page would seem like a good choice. Mine has a URL like `https://eur.delve.office.com/?u=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&v=work`.

How can I get that URL, i.e. the current user’s Delve profile page URL, via the Graph API?

Alternatively, is there another profile page URL I can get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URI isn't included in a user's profile but you can build the Delve URI without too much trouble.

The prototype for the URI is `https://{tenant-address}/?u={user-id}&v=work`.

If replace the `{tenant-address}` with your Delve address and the `{user-id}` with the `id` you receive from `/me` you can provide a link to that user's profile on Delve.

Comment: Thank you Marc! This seems like a good workaround. I’d rather retrieve a URL than construct it myself, but it’ll do for now.